# South 0.7.4: doesn't it support blank=True?

Tags: django, django-models, migration, django-south

I have a Django model and some its fields have the option `blank=True`.

But when i migrate the schema with south, this option isn't setted on database.

So doesn't South support this option?

In documentation i cannot find anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `blank` options doesn't apply to the actual database tables, it only effects how validation in the admin/forms is handled (you can enter blank strings). If you want to allow NULL then the option you want is `null=True`, which South does support.

See the discussion of blank vs null in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank)

Comment: I had skipped those 2 lines about null vs blank. Thanks.